Zig convert std.os.argv to C type argv
I have a zig project integrating with a c library (xlib). The library has a method that requires I pass the entire argv array to it as a parameter. In the zig extern definition the expected type of the library function's argv parameter is [*c][*c]u8.
As I am running linux I am using the non-cross-platform way of getting cli arguments in zig
var argv = std.os.argv;

The zig args are of type [][*:0]u8. I have 2 questions.

What is the most pragmatic way to cast/build the zig vargs into C vargs ( [][*:0]u8 -> [*c][*c]u8)
What exactly does [*c][*c]u8 mean?

Its been a long time since I've worked at this low a level. Am I right in understanding that [*c][*c]u8 is a list of c pointers, where each c pointer is the pointer to the first character of a null-terminated string?

I don't know anything about zig, but the array of pointers to char passed to the xlib C function will need to be terminated with a null pointer to mark the end of the list. In C's int main(int argc, char **argv), the array pointed toargv contains argc+1 pointers argv[0] to argv[argc], and argv[argc] will be a null pointer. The preceding pointers will be pointers to null terminated strings. argv[0] (if it is non-null, which it ought to be), is traditionally interpreted as pointing to the name of the program.


What is the most pragmatic way to cast/build the zig vargs into C vargs ( [][*:0]u8 -> [*c][*c]u8)

@ptrCast the .ptr property on the slice:
const argv = std.os.argv;
const c_ptr: [*c][*c]u8 = @ptrCast(argv.ptr);

(I don't think a pointer cast should be necessary here - it should be able to implicitly cast argv.ptr, but it refuses to implicitly cast the pointer child)

What exactly does [*c][*c]u8 mean? / Am I right in understanding that [*c][*c]u8 is a list of c pointers, where each c pointer is the pointer to the first character of a null-terminated string?

Zig pointers are a little bit confusing. There are pointers, slices, and value arrays with different options and similar syntax:

*u8 : a pointer to a u8 value. Can be dereferenced (value.*) but not indexed (value[0])
[*]u8 : an unknown length many-item pointer to a u8 value. Can be indexed but not dereferenced.
[*c]u8 : a one-or-many item pointer type that exists for c compatibility only. It can be both dereferenced and indexed.

in c, all pointers can be both dereferenced and indexed:
int myvalue = 0;
int* mypointer = &myvalue;
*mypointer = 1; // allowed
mypointer[0] = 2; // allowed


when translating c to zig, zig doesn't know if the c pointer is intended to be a single item or an array.
this is why it emits [*c] pointers, which allow both uses.


[]u8 : a slice, which is a pointer and a length. it is similar to struct {ptr: [*]u8, len: usize}. It can be indexed but not dereferenced.
[N]u8 : a value array type. This is not a pointer, even though it looks like one.

Unknown-length pointers and slices can have a sentinel value. [:0]u8 specifies that the slice has a 0 after the last item (slice[slice.len] == 0). [*:0]u8 specifies that while the length is not known, the item after the last item of the array should be a 0.
Both regular pointers and unknown-length pointers can cast implicitly to c compatibility pointers.
Now, to the question

[*c] one or many item pointer containing

[*c] one or many item pointer containing

u8





You are correct in your interpretation.

Because we know these are meant to be arrays, a better representation in zig would be [*][*:0]u8, an array of arrays. translate-c doesn't know this though, so it emits c compatibility pointers.

[*] unknown-length array pointer containing

[*:0] unknown-length 0-sentineled array pointer containing

u8





Because we also know the length of the outer array (with argv), we can combine the pointer [*][*:0]u8 and length usize into a slice: [][*:0]u8.
This is why std.os.argv returns [][*:0]u8.

Ah, so my initial attempt was correct! I had done exactly as you suggest. Unfortunately I am getting some error from the library (integer parameter out of range for operation). I am guessing its something specific with xlib and not to do with the conversion of the zig vargs to the c-style vargs

You can coerce without @ptrCast if you make the child pointers const: const c_ptr: [*c]const [*c]u8 = argv.ptr;.  In OP's case, the library header would need to declare the parameter as char *const argv[] or char *const *argv.
